# List of users with READ access to JSON file

Tags: java, permissions, ibm-midrange

I am trying to write a Java program for getting the list of all profiles on the iSeries server having greater than READ access to any object on the server based on configuration and store the information in a sample JSON file. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Hello, this question is off topic for Server Fault.  It would be on topic for Stack Overflow, if you posted the code that you had tried writing and pointed out where you were having a problem.

Comment: I wanted to know the iSeries command using which I can get the list of all the profiles in the server having greater than READ access to any object.

Comment: Do you have an issue with writing a Java program to do this, or using some administrative interface to get this data?

Comment: I am trying to use CommandCall function to run the iSeries command through java program and spool the data into a text file.

Comment: That should be fine for Stack Overflow, but you'll need to post what you've got so far.

Comment: Please edit your question.  Post the code that you tried using, what you actually got and what you expected to get.

Comment: There is no such command that will "list all the profiles in the server having greater than READ access to any object" unless you create the command yourself (or have someone create it for you). So, ask the question differently.

Comment: AS400 as400Object = new AS400(systemString);
CommandCall command = new CommandCall(as400Object); 
command.run("DSPOBJAUT OBJ(*ALL) OBJTYPE(*ALL) OUTPUT(*PRINT) AUTTYPE(*OBJECT)");
AS400Message[] messagelist = command.getMessageList(); 
for(int listNumber=0;listNumber<= messageList.length;listNumber++)
{String content = messageList[listNumber].getText();  
if(content.contains("*ALL") || content.contains("*CHANGE"))
{fop=new FileOutputStream(file,true);
fop.write(content);}}

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a list of users that have read authority to a SPECIFIC object or any object?

You can get a list of users using the [UserList](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/UserList.html) class.  From there you can (possibly) use the [QSYSPermission](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/QSYSPermission.html) class to determine permissions.

Getting the result into a JSON format is unrelated to IBM i concepts.